# How to find the smallest element in an user inputted array? Why the smallest element is displayed zero?

Tags: java, arrays, element

The code displays the sum, average, and largest element. It doesn't display the smallest element as the output is always zero. How do I display the smallest element in the array?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Average {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the number of elements:");
        int length = input.nextInt();
        
        int[] num = new int[length];
        System.out.println("Enter the "+ length +  " array elements:");
        int sum = 0;
         int large,small;
         large =small = num[0]; 
         
         for (int i=0; i<length;i++) {
            num[i] = input.nextInt();
            sum = sum+ num[i];
              }
         
        for (int i=0; i<length; ++i) {
            if (num[i]<small) {
                 small = num[i];
            }
              
             if(num[i]> large) {
                 large = num[i];
            }
             }
        
        double avg = sum/length;
        System.out.println("The sum is "+ sum);
        System.out.println("The average is "+ avg);
        System.out.println("The smallest element is "+ small);
        System.out.println("The largest element is "+ large);
        }
}
```

Comment: the initialization `large =small = num[0];` should be done after the user has input the values of the array, not before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class Average {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of elements:");
        int length = input.nextInt();

        int[] num = new int[length];
        System.out.println("Enter the " + length + " array elements:");
        int sum = 0;
        int large, small;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            num[i] = input.nextInt();
            sum = sum + num[i];
        }

        large = small = num[0]; // small should be assigned after num is input
        
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            if (num[i] < small) {
                small = num[i];
            }

            if (num[i] > large) {
                large = num[i];
            }
        }

        double avg = sum / length;
        System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
        System.out.println("The average is " + avg);
        System.out.println("The smallest element is " + small);
        System.out.println("The largest element is " + large);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yea, it's happening because by default your field small is equal to 0.

And now let's look step by step your if statement

```
        if (num[i]<small) {
             small = num[i];
        }
```

example for numbers: 22,11,6,

```
So first step is num[0] < 0, why 0 as mention before small = 0 by default
Step two num[1] < 0, small stills stay 0
Step Three num[2] < 0, small stills stay 0.
```

What are you missing, you need to assign value to small at the first iteration of your for loop, for example:

```
       for (int i=0; i<length; ++i) {
            if(i == 0){
                small = num[i];
            }
            if (num[i]<small) {
                small = num[i];
            }

            if(num[i]> large) {
                large = num[i];
            }
        }
```

Now your program should work :)

Answer (score 0):

if you use java 8 or above, you can use the stream method of Arrays. it simplifies work with arrays. [for more info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)

firstly import the Arrays as `import java.util.Arrays;`

```
System.out.println("The sum is " + Arrays.stream(num).sum());
System.out.println("The average is " + Arrays.stream(num).average());
System.out.println("The smallest element is " + Arrays.stream(num).min());
System.out.println("The largest element is " + Arrays.stream(num).max());
```